# How to hide/deal with dotted (.) folders in windows?

Tags: windows

There are a lot of applications that uses the dot notation + application name to store it's data. This is common on *NIX systems but **it's not recommended by** [FreeDesktopStandards](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-0.6.html), in fact they should use the `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` variable, which usually is mapped to `$HOME/.config` directory.

For instance is very common for an application `xyz` to create in the current User default folder the following folder `~/.xyz` to store it's data. I tried mapping `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` to the Windows equivalent variable (`%APPDATA%`), but no luck.

**So my question is, is there a way to definitely hide these dotted folders?**

Example:
[image]

Comment: File bugs with the relevant projects. If enough people pester them, this might get fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the files as hidden by opening the command prompt and running:

```
for /f %f in ('dir C:\Users\Marcos\.* /b') do attrib +h %f
```

This will look for any files and folders in `C:\Users\Marcos\` beginning with a period and mark them with the hidden attribute. You can make this recuresive (i.e. it will search sub folders) by adding `/s` inside the single quote containing the `dir` command.

You can also specify a different folder, by changing the path (or removing the path and running it in the desired directory.

As long as explorer is set to [not show hidden files and folders](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/394-hidden-files-folders-show-hide.html) you won't see them anymore, otherwise you will see them but they are slightly transparent.

Comment: I see that the world needs a _Useless Use of `FOR`_ award to go alongside the _Useless Use of `cat`_ award.  ☺

Comment: @JdeBP: This is more like useless use of `\`ls\`` instead of wildcards. The `for` loop itself (`for /r`?) does make some sense for recursively finding all files/directories matching `.*`. (Does `attrib` even accept wildcards?)

Comment: Yeah, apparently `attrib` does accept wild cards, I thought it didn't and only tested it now that @grawity mentioned it. Ahh well, answer is good if you need recursion (check the entire partition?). `attrib +h .*` would have done the trick in this particular case.

Comment: Not only does `attrib` accept wildcards, it also has an `/S` option.  (It didn't have `/S` prior to MS-DOS 3.3.  But it has pretty much _always_ supported wildcards, and _always_ supported `/S` on Windows NT, if memory serves correctly, which is the target system here.)  It truly is `FOR` that is uselessly used in cases such as this.